# Printing HTML to PDF through Out-Printer

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to PoSH. I've been trying to automate printing HTML files to PDF using Microsoft's Print to PDF printer. My approach has been to `Get-Content <file> | Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft Print To PDF"`.

This generates a PDF file with my HTML file in plain text.

What I am trying to do, is to print the rendered file and preserve CSS to a PDF file - much like saving a website as a PDF file in a browser.

I have tried countless other options to no avail - any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Other option: from powershell, open the html with a Microsoft browser and then try to print the file to pdf from there.

Comment: Looks like there are a number of options described here such as using `wkhtmltopdf` or headless chrome. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/06/create-pdf-web-application/ If one of these works for you please document in an answer. Of course you should be able to automate any of these through powershell